# IOS application using Cordova, Application font size not changing when i change font size in settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

I am creating IOS application using Cordova, In Application font size not changing, when i change font size in General settings. I searched a lot but cannot find the solution.In my application i am not using MobileAccessibility.

```
window.MobileAccessibility.usePreferredTextZoom(false);
```

Even though its not working.

Comment: can you edit the question to show how you are currently changing the font size?

Comment: I am using media and query to set the font size
@media ( min-width: 767px) {}

Comment: did you check with safari and remote debugging that the style was applied, and not overriden by another one?

Comment: yes i checked but its not overridden by anyone.

Comment: the rendered visual side of a cordova application being an HTML page, if you see the style applied, it should work. Maybe your screen size is smaller than 767px? that's the only other thing i could see that can fail here

Comment: Even i use 387 px also same problem, i need font to be dynamic,  font-size need to change if i change font size in ios settings

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my problem.

I removed the body font size

```
font-size: 100%;
```

and by adding font in my body tag, resolved my problem.

```
font: -apple-system-body;
```